# Encrypt SSN column in a list

Tags: security, column

I need to encrypt social security column in a list. What are my options?

ps: Did not find Encryption in the Tags.

Actually, looking for something like this (Column Level Security, but non commercial solution)
http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-column-level-security.aspx

This may be new topic or a topic no one wants to talk about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't if this is acceptable by your business user or policy. This help hide or set permission who can see a given field.

http://splistdisplaysetting.codeplex.com/

Comment: This may do it. I still need to confirm it with the Travel Dept to what's acceptable by them and policy. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use Transparent Data Encryption for the entire SharePoint Content database.

Comment: Is that overkill when I just want to encrypt one column not the entire content database.

Comment: Absolutely, but it is your only choice if you're using the built-in List functionality.

Comment: OMG. For real. Microsoft did a really good job on this. and Column level security. Thanks Trevor for the info. It helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom secure field. see this codeplex solution: http://cryptocollaboration.codeplex.com/

FYI: I have seen issues with custom fields (almost all the time) either with jquery or 3rd party or nintex. So that's something you will have calculate when implementing custom fields.

Good Luck

Comment: I know it's a PIA to go through this as this should a standard feature especially in SP 2010 as you would imagine this is an improved version. Hey, take a look at this which hides the value http://www.infoq.com/articles/Dressel-Gogolowicz-wss-security.